# Partial view postback from a standard Html form with MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery-plugins, partial-views

I have a file upload button on my MVC view. After the file is uploaded, my `FileList` partial view on the page should refresh.

I tried to upload with `Ajax.BeginForm()`, but have discovered that Ajax will not submit file data.

I've got the file upload working now by using the [jQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started), which lets you ajaxify the normal `Html.BeginForm()` submit method.

Is is still possible to trigger the partial page update using this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah you could use the success option in the .ajaxForm to pass back data from the file upload and then pass that data to the PartialView or just refresh the partial.

```
     // Setup the from plugin
    $('#formId').ajaxForm(
                          success: function(data) { UploadSuccess(data); },
                          dataType: 'json', 
                          iframe:true);
    $('#formId').submit();

    // Success callback fundtion
    function UploadSuccess(data)
    {
        // You can then access any data in the JSON object and pass it in the route to the partial
        $('#divId').load('/FileList/' + data.FileName);
    }

// Original HTML of partial
<div id="divId">
    <%Html.RenderPartial("FileList");%>
</div>

        // Action to handle upload
        public FileUploadJSONResult Upload()
        {
            FileUploadJSONResult result;

            try
            {
                if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
                {
                    //  Logic to save file goes here

                    result = new FileUploadJSONResult()
                    {
                        Data = new
                        {
                            FileName = "Test filename",
                            ErrorMessage = string.Empty
                        }
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    result = new FileUploadJSONResult
                    {
                        Data = new
                        {
                            FileName = string.Empty,
                            LogicalName = string.Empty,
                            ErrorMessage = "No file to upload. Please select a file to upload."
                        }
                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Exception root = e;
                while ((root.InnerException) != null)
                {
                    root = root.InnerException;
                }

                result = new FileUploadJSONResult
                {
                    Data = new
                    {
                        FileName = string.Empty,
                        LogicalName = string.Empty,
                        ErrorMessage = root.Message
                    }
                };
            }

            return result;
        }

// Then needed to wrap the JSON result due to the iframe textarea issue with this plugin
public class FileUploadJSONResult : JsonResult
    {  
        /// <summary>
        /// The following explanation of this code is from http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form:
        /// 
        ///  Since it is not possible to upload files using the browser's XMLHttpRequest object, the Form Plugin 
        ///  uses a hidden iframe element to help with the task. This is a common technique, but it has inherent limitations. 
        ///  The iframe element is used as the target of the form's submit operation which means that the server response is 
        ///  written to the iframe. This is fine if the response type is HTML or XML, but doesn't work as well if the 
        ///  response type is script or JSON, both of which often contain characters that need to be repesented using 
        ///  entity references when found in HTML markup.
        ///  To account for the challenges of script and JSON responses, the Form Plugin allows these responses to be 
        ///  embedded in a textarea element and it is recommended that you do so for these response types when used in 
        ///  conjuction with file uploads. Please note, however, that if a file has not been selected by the user for the 
        ///  file input then the request uses normal XHR to submit the form (not an iframe). This puts the burden on your 
        ///  server code to know when to use a textarea and when not to. If you like, you can use the iframe option of the 
        ///  plugin to force it to always use an iframe mode and then your server can always embed the response in a textarea. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">Controller context</param>
        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            this.ContentType = "text/html";
            context.HttpContext.Response.Write("<textarea>");
            base.ExecuteResult(context);
            context.HttpContext.Response.Write("</textarea>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer pointed me in the right direction. Although it's actually much simpler than this, as I can directly return the html from the partial view instead of returning a json data object.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you should be able to provide a callback function to the `success` property of the jQuery Form plugin (check out this link for all of the options: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object).

Then inside that javascript function you can do whatever updates to the FileList partial view that you need to... whether that be a `GET` request to update the partial view, or just capturing the `responseText` from the success callback function of the jQuery Form plugin.